# Screen size and device orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on the task which is related to common screen size detection and device orientation.

Is there any built-in solution for detecting screen size (normal, large, xlarge) in runtime without adding something to resources files?

Comment: Why do you need to get the screen size in terms of google screen buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check Device Orientation

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(orientation ==  Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

    }else if(orientation ==  Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){}
```

> Screen size detection

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) { // Large screen
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) { //Normal sized screen
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {//Small sized screen
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {//XLarge sized screen}
```